# Is it possible link link to kik groups?

Tags: kik

I know I can make link to a username using this format: https://kik.me/username

Is there an equivalent to linking to public groups knowing just the group name?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot link to a group using just a name. You can give someone the "#" if it is a public group, but not a link. You can however, create an invite link for a group that will have a random string in it if you click on the share button in a group chats roster, regardless of if its public or private.